# Is it Firefox or Geckodriver, which creates "rust_mozprofile" directory

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

Whenever we invoke Firefox, under '/tmp' directory rust_mozprofile directories are getting created. As Firefox internally calls Geckodriver we are not sure whether Firefox or Geckodriver is creating rust_mozprofile directory.

I do want to know whether Geckodriver or Firefox because, my '/tmp' directory is having less memory.

So the question is I really want to modify the path of creating directories for rust_mozprofile.

I am using below technologies,

- Selenium - 3.3.0
- Firefox - 52.2.0
- Geckodriver - 13

Please give us some suggestion, if there is any.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a closer look at the *geckodriver v0.18.0* logs closely you will observe the very first occurrence of `rust_mozprofile` occurs in the following line:

```
1504762617094   Marionette  CONFIG  Matched capabilities: {"browserName":"firefox","browserVersion":"56.0","platformName":"windows_nt","platformVersion":"6.2","pageLoadStrategy":"normal","acceptInsecureCerts":false,"timeouts":{"implicit":0,"pageLoad":300000,"script":30000},"rotatable":false,"specificationLevel":0,"moz:processID":5848,"moz:profile":"C:\\Users\\AtechM_03\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rust_mozprofile.OfFuR9ogm33d","moz:accessibilityChecks":false,"moz:headless":false}
```

This log clearly indicates that [marionette](/questions/tagged/marionette) is being configured with:

```
"moz:profile":"C:\\Users\\AtechM_03\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rust_mozprofile.OfFuR9ogm33d"
```

And this configuration is done by the [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) instance i.e. the *GeckoDriver*.

It's the *GeckoDriver* which internally configures the *Marionette* which in-turn initiates the *Mozilla Firefox Browser*.

IMO, this workflow is in practice since we migrated from the *Legacy Firefox* to *Marionette* based *Firefox*. Hence the same must be the case with *Geckodriver - 13* as well.

---

### Update:

GeckoDriver as an application/exe file:
[image]

Comment: Your answer gives us some clarity now. After this the problematic question is whether we can change the rust_mozprofile path. If it is there, then can you let us know where I can do that. Thank you.

Comment: @abc Yes, you can do that pretty easily by changing the location in the default configuration & build the customized geckodriver at your end.

Comment: Ok. But as you see when we are using windows, geckodriver is a jar file which can be edited. But in linux environment we have geckodriver as executable file. Is there anyone where we can edit that file.

Comment: @abc Even on Windows geckodriver is a application/exe file. Updated image in the Answer.

Comment: So do you have any insight on modifying the default configuration ?

Comment: @abc If use `geckodriver` in default configuration, `geckodriver` will keep on scooping a new `rust_mozprofile` on each run. **_Probably(unsure)_**, to get rid of it, you may consider creating a separate `Firefox Profile` and use the same `Firefox Profile` in your `Test Execution`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153841/discussion-between-abc-and-debanjanb).

Comment: How would you find "the location in the default configuration"? I opened up the source code of geckodriver in pycharm and went through every file.  Never found any path that contained 'Temp'  or 'rust' etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the location with the TMPDIR envvar. It's also useful to set both TMP and TEMP for other programs.

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to use `driver.quit()` this closes all browsers and takes care of the profiles

Another solution is to add a custom profile

```
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('specify location to profile .default') 
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
```

Comment: custom profile isn't a solution at all, since all those directories are still created under the `/tmp` anyway. actually, in my case it creates even two identical directories with the same copy of the specified profile: `/tmp/rust_mozprofileXXX` and `/tmp/tmpXXX` (on Linux), so I think there is no way to specify a custom path that will be used to create a new profile directory (from scratch or from existing profile, doesn't matter in this case).

Comment: even more - we can't get the actual path to this `rust_mozprofile` directory from Selenium, so we can only rely on `driver.quit()` as you mentioned (and in case of any unhandled error - we still have `rust_mozprofile` coffins under the system `/tmp`

Comment: probably we can parse the `geckodriver`'s log at the run time to get the path to `rust_mozprofile` directory, but it sounds like a super dirty hack to me

Comment: @d-d Actually we can get the actual path even before using the driver, with `fp.path`. However, it is still a copy and not the specified profile path.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I solved it by changing the Environment settings in Windows. Meaning that I changed the directory for the TMP and TEMP files, and after a reboot, the rust_mozprofile folder was generated where I wanted it.

This is the source I used: https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/how-to-use-geckodriver/ Specifically the "Set property in Environment Variables:-" section.

Sadly this will effect all Software that saves files to those folders. (In my case that is what I wanted though.) If there is a way to make only the rust_mozprofile folder be created in a specific directory through the program, I would love to learn more.

Comment: That link is broken now. Is there a new version?