# Is there a way to clear session data to ensure a clean session is initiated each time?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

For IE you would use capabilities like this:

```
DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
cap.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IE_ENSURE_CLEAN_SESSION, true);
```

and possibly in combination with

```
 driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
```

How could this be achieved using Chrome and ChromeDriver?

Comment: Chrome starts each session with randomly created profile without any cookies or cache. It starts a clean session by default, until you change it.

Answer (score 6):

While we work with **`Internet Explorer Driver`** we use the field **`IE_ENSURE_CLEAN_SESSION`**

### **`IE_ENSURE_CLEAN_SESSION`**

As per the JavaDocs **`IE_ENSURE_CLEAN_SESSION`** is the Capability that defines whether to clean or not browser cache before launching Internet Explorer by IEDriverServer and is configured as follows :

```
DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
cap.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IE_ENSURE_CLEAN_SESSION, true);
```

---

Now let us have a look at **`GeckoDriver`** which follows the **`WebDriver Spec`**.

### **`GeckoDriver`** / **`moz:profile`** / **`rust_mozprofile`**

If you have a closer look at the **`geckodriver`** logs closely you will observe that each time **`geckodriver`** is called a new **`moz:profile`** is scopped out and the details of **`rust_mozprofile`** occurs in the following line:

```
Marionette  CONFIG  Matched capabilities: {"browserName":"firefox","browserVersion":"56.0","platformName":"windows_nt","platformVersion":"6.2","pageLoadStrategy":"normal","acceptInsecureCerts":false,"timeouts":{"implicit":0,"pageLoad":300000,"script":30000},"rotatable":false,"specificationLevel":0,"moz:processID":5848,"moz:profile":"C:\\Users\\AtechM_03\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rust_mozprofile.OfFuR9ogm33d","moz:accessibilityChecks":false,"moz:headless":false}
```

This log clearly indicates that Marionette scoops out a new **`"moz:profile":"C:\\Users\\AtechM_03\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rust_mozprofile.OfFuR9ogm33d"`** and this configuration is handled by the WebDriver instance i.e. the **`GeckoDriver`**.

You can find a more detailed discussion on **`moz:profile`** in [**`Is it Firefox or Geckodriver, which creates “rust_mozprofile” directory`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46088442/is-it-firefox-or-geckodriver-which-creates-rust-mozprofile-directory/46089240#46089240) discussion.

---

### **`ChromeDriver`**

**`ChromeDriver`** which is following the same **`WebDriver Spec`** does abides (will be abiding) by the same suite.

---

> Incase you are using any stored **`FirefoxProfile`** or **`ChromeProfile`**, **`WebDriver`** will pick up the existing profile where the **`Stored Browser Configurations`** are picked up for reuse.

---

### **`driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();`**

Irespective of New/Existing **`FirefoxProfile`** or **`ChromeProfile`** if you add the line :

```
driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
```

Only the cookies gets deleted only to be get restored back to support the **`Active Browser Session`**