# How to fix "WebDriverException: Message: connection refused"?

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, jenkins, geckodriver

I am using a very complex setup to test various non-public webpages. I use `jenkins` to run the `python-selenium` tests within a `docker`image. That way, I am completly independent of the jenkins environment and can create my own environment. In this environment I have the following software installed:

- Firefox: 57.0.1
- geckodriver: 0.18.0
- nosetests: 1.3.7
- selenium: 3.8.0

The selenium tests create the `WebDriver` the following way:

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", self.downloadpath)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.useDownloadDir", True)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
profile.set_preference("pdfjs.disabled", True)
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk",
"application/force-download, image/png, text/html, text/plain, "
"image/tiff, text/csv, application/zip, application/octet-stream")
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.alertOnEXEOpen", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.focusWhenStarting", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.alertOnEXEOpen", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.closeWhenDone", True)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.useWindow", False)
profile.set_preference("services.sync.prefs.sync.browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",
False)
self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile, log_path = logfile)
```

where `logfile` and `self.downloadpath` are two valid paths in the docker setup.

The whole test suite consists of 6 independant test cases, each with the same setup as above. They normally run fine and complete without problems.

But ***without any change*** to the tests or the general setup, a test sometimes fails with the following error message:

```
  File "/root/tests/bsp_usecase_tests/tools/basicsuite.py", line 210, in set_driver_firefox
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile, log_path = logfile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 158, in __init__
    keep_alive=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 154, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 243, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 311, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 237, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
WebDriverException: Message: connection refused
```

I have two questions:

1. What connection is refused here? What is the meaning of the error message
2. How can I possibly fix this error?

**Addendum**:

- When I used a `time.sleep(10)` just before the `webdriver.Firefox` line, the error did not show up anymore. Shoud I put that line in a while-try-except loop?

Comment: do you use a virtual display for running the selenium tests? Afaik jenkins runs in headless environment, so you need `Xvfb` to instantiate a firefox driver. Newer versions of firefox also can work in a headless environment - to use it, you have to pass the flag in options: `opts = selenium.webdriver.firefox.options.Options(); opts.add_argument('-headless');driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, firefox_options=opts)`.

Comment: This error/stack-trace indicates that the driver failed to start its internal server to communicate with the python client. It could be a race condition on the generated port number or maybe the docker image has a lack of memory which is not recycle on time when the next test starts. In any case your issue requires a reproductible example and an analysis of the logs from the OS, browser and driver which are not present in your post.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error you are seeing is :

```
WebDriverException: Message: connection refused
```

As per the documentation [**`WebDriverException`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/common/selenium.common.exceptions.html#selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException) is the **Base webdriver exception** which is as follows :

```
exception selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException(msg=None, screen=None, stacktrace=None)
```

So `connection is refused here` means that **`Selenium`** is unable to establish the connecting which you wanted to establish through :

```
self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile, log_path = logfile)
```

A possible solution would be to provide the complete name of the `logfile` along with the `logical location` of the `logfile` (from `Project Level`) as follows :

```
self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, log_path='./Log/geckodriver.log')
```

Here you can find a similar [`Discussion`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47965426/how-to-store-console-output-of-python-selenium-program-in-to-file/47965702#47965702)

Again, as you mentioned `When I used a time.sleep(10) just before the webdriver.Firefox line, the error did not show up anymore`, so I assume there was an instance of **`GeckoDriver`** and **`Firefox Browser`** client active previously. Hence, similarly as @Florent B. mentioned you have to shield your script against facing [**Race Around Condition**](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-race-around-condition-in-an-operating-system) which can stem out from either of the following :

- Accessing the same **logfile** by the new session which previous session have't released yet.
- Accessing the same **port number** by **`GeckoDriver`** or **`Marionette`** by the new session which previous session have't released yet.
- Lack of access to **CPU**
- Lack of **Physical Memory**
- Lack of **Swap Memory**
- Lack of **Disc Cache**
- Lack of **Network Bandwidth**
- `Docker Image` ran **out of memory**

Here you can find a similar [`Discussion`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48045663/opening-more-than-9-sessions-with-selenium/48049790#48049790).

As per the above mentioned causes, you need to follow a few steps as follows :

- Always use the latest released version of [**`Selenium-Python`** client](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium), **`WebDriver variant`** ([**`GeckoDriver`**](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases)) and **`Web Browser`** (**`Firefox Browser`**)
- Always use **quit()** in the `tearDown()` method so that the **`webdriver`** and the **`webclient`** both are properly destroyed.
- `Clean` the **Project Workspace** from your `IDE` before and after executing your `Test Suite`.
- `Clear` the **Browser Cache** before and after the execution of your `Tests`
- Use `CCleaner` tool regularly to wipe away the **OS chores** including the stale [**`rust_mozprofile directories`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46088442/is-it-firefox-or-geckodriver-which-creates-rust-mozprofile-directory/46089240#46089240).

Comment: I can change that. Your answer does not epxplain, however, what a `WebDriverException` is, nor does your answer discuss possible fitting reasons why I get this error just only occassional...

Answer (score 5):

> What connection is refused here? What is the meaning of the error message

The connection between the Python webdriver API and your Firefox web browser. Well, not the connection itself, but a single request that the webdriver sent was "rejected" by the browser. Note that this works through the [JSON Wire protocol](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol) - JSON over HTTP.

> How can I possibly fix this error?

Usually, in case of error like this, the most common reason is a *compatibility issue*. In other words, I suspect that your *`geckodriver` version 0.18.0 is too old for the Firefox 57*. Upgrade `geckodriver` to the latest stable version (currently [0.19.1](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases)).

Answer (score 3):

A quick fix to try for anyone else out there struggling with this or similar errors -- I found that deleting my `geckodriver.log` file got rid of this error.

This is implied in the "Clean the Project Workspace" part of DebanjanB's answer, but I just wanted to share the concrete action that fixed it for me. Note that I was not using a test suite like the original poster.

I imagine what happened for me was that I had previous `webdriver.Firefox` instances that never got to `driver.close()` in my code due to an error in another part of my code, which I was still debugging, and they had not released the log file `geckodriver.log`.

Thus I imagine this issue might also be solved by renaming the log file or writing to a different log file.

Comment: Which OS are you using? can you guess what would be the log file location if I'm using geckodriver on Spring (deployed on tomcat)

Comment: @MihirJoshi, I was using Linux. I am not sure where the log file location would be in your case. I did this quite a while ago so don't really remember the details any more, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and found that it was a **permissions problem**. I am running **Selenium within apache**, and the apache folder did not have the correct permissions. Either selenium, geckodriver, or firefox tries creating files and folders in the `/var/www/` directory, and it does not have permissions to do so.

You can fix this with the following command:

```
chmod a+rwx /var/www/
```

The above command will work, but is potentially insecure as it gives everyone access to the folder. If you want to make it a bit more secure, try:

```
chown www-data /var/www/
```

This are both quick hacks, the better way would be to figure out why geckodriver is creating files in the folder, and change that folder setting (I haven't done this).