# Opening more than 9 sessions with Selenium

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to use Selenium to visit a website with a few dozen sessions at a time, but whenever I try and setup more than 9 sessions, it says "chromedriver.exe is not responding" and the sessions start closing themselves.

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

url = "website URL"
amount = 36

def generateBrowsers():
    for x in range(0, amount):
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/Users/user/Documents/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")
        driver.get(url)
        time.sleep(3)

generateBrowsers()
```

Does anyone know what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logically, your code block have **No Errors**.

But as you are trying to open **36 Sessions** at a time you need to consider the following facts :

- Each call to **`driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/Users/user/Documents/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")`** will initiate :

  ```
  1. A new WebDriver instance
  2. A new Web Browser instance
  ```
- Each of the **`WebDriver`** instance and **`Web Browser`** instance will need to occupy some amount of :

  ```
  1. CPU
  2. Memory
  3. Network
  4. Cache
  ```

Now, as you execute your `Test Suite` from your system which also runs a lot other `Applications` (some of them may be on `Start Up`) tries to accomodate within the available **`CPU`**, **`Memory`**, **`Network`** or **`Cache`**. So whenever, the usage of mentioned parameters gets beyond the **threshhold level**, either the next new **`chromedriver.exe`** or the **`chrome.exe`** will be unable to spawn out properly. In your case **`chromedriver.exe`** was unable to spawn out. Hence you see the error :

```
chromedriver.exe is not responding
```

### Solution

If you have a requirement of spawning **36 Sessions** at a time you need to use :

- **`Selenium in Grid Configuration`** : `Selenium Grid` consists of a **`Hub`** and **`Node`** and you will be able to distribute required number of sessions among number of `Nodes`.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed response, really helped.