# how to resolve "ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused" error for selenium python code?

Tags: python, eclipse, macos, selenium, pydev

1) Using pyDev in eclipse on a mac for writing selenium automation 
2) python code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Remote(desired_capabilities=webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.SAFARI)
#browser=webdriver.Safari()
browser.get('http://www.google.com')
```

3) Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1318, in do_open
    encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1239, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 964, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 936, in connect
    (self.host,self.port), self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 724, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 713, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused
```

Comment: Does your tests gets executed successfully with `browser=webdriver.Safari()`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix "WebDriverException: Message: connection refused"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47920639/how-to-fix-webdriverexception-message-connection-refused)

Comment: same issue even with browser=webdriver.safari()

Comment: what was the solution?