# What does "Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon" mean?

Tags: python, selenium, jenkins

I am using a very complex setup to test various non-public webpages. I use `jenkins` to run the `python-selenium` tests within a `docker`image. That way, I am completely independent of the jenkins environment and can create my own environment. In this environment I have the following software installed:

- Ubuntu 16.04.3
- Firefox: Mozilla Firefox 57.0.1
- geckodriver: 0.18.0
- nosetests: 1.3.7
- selenium: 3.8.0

When running the tests, which mostly succeed, I see in the `geckodriver.log` output messages like

```
(firefox:55): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
/usr/bin/dbus-launch terminated abnormally without any error message
```

My questions:

- What does this message mean?
- Could that be an indication of the reason why sometimes the tests are failing?
- If so, how to fix it?

Comment: However, the application was unable to reach its tools in the System menu. Execution rights do not grant access to the system components(One or more of your sub-processes are unowned,).

Comment: I am not quite sure I understand. What 'tools', and what 'System menu'? Does this just happen from time to time? Is it normal?

Comment: This seems to be an operating system issue. Dbus is an interprocess communication library. What kind of linux os you are using?

Comment: Its Ubuntu 16.04.3.

Comment: Here you can find a hint to avoid this kind of warnings
 https://askubuntu.com/questions/237893/firefox-sluggish-printing-error-message

Comment: Thanks. But are these warnings 'harmful'? Can they possibly make the selenium tests fail?

Comment: Remove Firefox from the system and install the version supported by the Gecko driver. **firefox:55 != Firefox 57.0.1**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The error you are seeing is :

```
(firefox:55): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
/usr/bin/dbus-launch terminated abnormally without any error message
```

So it is clear *Firefox* attempts to connect to **D-BUS daemon** and fails as *dbus-launch* gets terminated abnormally.

---

### dbus-launch

**dbus-launch** is basically the utility to start a message bus by firefox through a shell script. It would normally be called from a user's login scripts. *dbus-launch* launches a session bus instance and print the address and `pid` of that instance to standard output.

You can read more about *dbus-launch* from the [Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dbus-launch)

---

### Root Cause

This error can arise if you use `su` (root), `sudo`, `suedit`, `gksu`. The main reason is `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` retains its value when you `su` instead of picking up the value in `/root/.dbus/session-bus`.

Here you will find a detailed discussion on [GConf Error: No D-BUS daemon running?! How to reinstall or fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135573/gconf-error-no-d-bus-daemon-running-how-to-reinstall-or-fix).

Another possible reason may be the base `Firefox` Browser version may be an older version on which updates were taken to reach the current version.

---

### Solution :

There are a couple of solutions available to address this [ubuntu](/questions/tagged/ubuntu) related issue as follows :

- Before you start Firefox you have to type `export $(dbus-launch)`
- However this may result into another error with `NSS_USE_SHARED_DB`. So you have to use `export NSS_USE_SHARED_DB=ENABLED` as well.
- The most convenient way would be to put all the configuration with in `.bashrc` file :

  ```
  export $(dbus-launch)
  export NSS_USE_SHARED_DB=ENABLED
  firefox &
  ```

This [discussion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/237893/firefox-sluggish-printing-error-message) speaks about the solution in details.

- If `dbus-launch` is not installed on your system you have to install `dbus-x11` package which contains the **dbus-launch** program.
- An effective solution would be to uninstall the older base version of *Firefox* Browser and install a recent released *GA* version of *Firefox* Browser.

---

### Best Approach

The issue with **dbus-launch** was addressed properly by both *Ubuntu* and *Mozila*. To overcome this error you need to follow the below mentioned steps :

- Keep your *Ubuntu* [os](/questions/tagged/os) updated with the [Latest Patch Releases](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) and updates.
- Always use the latest released version of [Selenium-Python client](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium), [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) variant e.g. [GeckoDriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) and Web Browser, e.g. *Firefox Browser*.
- *Clean* and *Build* the *Project Workspace* afresh through your *IDE* before and after executing your *Test Suite*.
- *Clear* the *Browser Cache* before and after the execution of your *Tests*.
- If you have to *uninstall* any of the *Web Client* variants (e.g. *Mozilla Firefox*) you can use *Revo Uninstallar* with *Moderate Memory Scan* so that the stale **registry settings** are discarded.
- Use *CCleaner* tool regularly to wipe away the **OS chores** including the stale [rust_mozprofile directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46088442/is-it-firefox-or-geckodriver-which-creates-rust-mozprofile-directory/46089240#46089240).

Answer (score 3):

For me the solution was to install dbus-x11

```
apt install dbus-x11
```

Answer (score 2):

> What does this message mean?

[DBus](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/dbus/) is a message bus system for interprocess commutation. There is an open `geckodriver` issue on a similar if not the same subject:

- [request to geckodriver fails with no meaningful log entry when there is no access to $HOME/.mozilla or $HOME/.cache](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/716)

> Could that be an indication of the reason why sometimes the tests are failing?

The warning should not really affect the tests but it's difficult to speculate about your intermittent test failures without seeing what is actually happening in your tests.

> If so, how to fix it?

Here are some things to try:

- upgrade `geckodriver` to the [latest stable version](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) (currently 0.19.1)
- update Firefox to the *latest nightly version* (currently 58)
- try [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/237917/191925)
- try [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/202481/191925)