# Turn on logging for gecko driver in Selenium Node JS

Tags: node.js, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I am currently using **Selenium with Node.Js** and **FireFox** and would like to turn on the logging feature for the *geckodriver*.

But am not sure how.
Plus I would also like to know where the logs will be found.
Here is currently how I instantiate the driver.

```
var fOptions = new firefox.Options();
var profile = new firefox.Profile('./fProfile');
fOptions.setProfile(profile);    
driver[0] = new Builder().withCapabilities({'browserName': 'firefox'}).setFirefoxOptions(fOptions).build();
```

Comment: Are you able to see any of the _geckodriver_ logs in your console by default?

Comment: No I do not,though I should mention I am using electron framework together with node JS.

Comment: IMO, you should edit the _tags_, remove `firefox` tag and add `electron framework` tag so some volunteers frequenting `electron framework` tag can help us out. Had it been _Java_ or _Python_ clients I could have helped you out.

Comment: Could you explain it with just the plain NodeJs I might just switch to it for a bit of a debugging session. That would still be an answer am interested in

Comment: But how would that help you as in the first place you are `No I do not` able to see any of the _geckodriver_ logs in your console by default.

Comment: electron from my experience may hide the logs, so from what I gathered is that it will display the log on the console... I haven't tried it yet with plain node, let me try.