# Geckodriver is creating rust_mozprofile directories when I use Selenium Webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I am using Selenium Python bindings with `geckodriver`. After each browser session `rust_mozprofile` directories are created in my Windows 7 Temp directory. The houndreds of newly created directories can quickly add up to 5 - 6 GB.

I looked for a solution, but I haven't found anything so far. I can manually delete these directories, but this is not optimal. Is there a way to solve this problem programmatically in Selenium?

**This is not a duplicate, here is why:**

I checked the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46088442/is-it-firefox-or-geckodriver-which-creates-rust-mozprofile-directory) but it does not solve my problem. I would like to find a way to create a separate Firefox Profile and use it in Selenium Test Execution or any other way to solve this problem programmatically in Selenium if possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it Firefox or Geckodriver, which creates "rust\_mozprofile" directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46088442/is-it-firefox-or-geckodriver-which-creates-rust-mozprofile-directory)

Answer (score 1):

A solution is to use driver.quit() instead of driver.close()

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15067107/difference-between-webdriver-dispose-close-and-quit)

Another solution is to add a custom profile

`fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('specify location to profile .default')
 driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)`

Comment: I'm using FirefoxProfile but it still copy that profile folder to /tmp/rust_mozprofile...
I checked geckodriver.log , I saw this :
Running command: "/usr/bin/firefox" "-marionette" "-profile" "/tmp/rust_mozprofile.ZeoXTluZ5ZCT"
How can I stop creating profile folder, or at least move it to another folder. Because I created many Xvfb process at the same time while boot partition is small then it make full hard disk

Comment: This line `fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('specify location to profile .default')` will copy whatever profile you have at that location, paste it to `/tmp/rust_mozprofileasdf123` and then driver will use this copied version of profile.