# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: There is not enough space on the disk error using Selenium and WebDriver through Java

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, space, diskspace

I am running the TESTNG test in Maven setup . While i am running the testng , I am getting the following exception:

Note: Checked the dependency and there is no error in pom.xml

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: There is not enough space on the disk
Command duration or timeout: 914 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:19:58.91Z'
```

Comment: What did you in relation to "there is not enough space on disk"?

Answer (score 4):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: There is not enough space on the disk 
Command duration or timeout: 914 milliseconds 
Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:19:58.91Z'
```

...implies that the **WebDriver** instance was unable to initiate/spawn a new **WebBrowser** session as there was **not enough space**.

---

If you take a closer look at the *GeckoDriver* startup logs you can observe the creation of `rust_mozprofile` as follows:

```
1566480787996   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe" "-marionette" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "C:\\Users\\Debanjan.B\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rust_mozprofile.7diW2pWdtxN9"
```

This log clearly indicates that a new profile i.e. `C:\\Users\\Debanjan.B\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rust_mozprofile.7diW2pWdtxN9` is scoped out for *Marionette* everytime *GeckoDriver* initiates a new **Firefox** web browsing session. On a successful `quit()` this temporary **rust_mozprofile** gets deleted.

> You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:
>
> - [Is it Firefox or Geckodriver, which creates “rust_mozprofile” directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46088442/is-it-firefox-or-geckodriver-which-creates-rust-mozprofile-directory/46089240#46089240)
> - [Selenium : How to stop geckodriver process impacting PC memory, without calling
>     driver.quit()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47999568/selenium-how-to-stop-geckodriver-process-impacting-pc-memory-without-calling/48003289#48003289)

If you weren't invoking `quit()` there is a possibility of `..\AppData\Local\Temp` directory may get filled up with **stale** `rust_mozprofiles`.

---

### Solution

An ideal solution would be to:

- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully. You can find a relevant discussion in:

  - [PhantomJS web driver stays in memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45985008/phantomjs-web-driver-stays-in-memory/45985790#45985790)
- (*WindowsOS only*) Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*.
- (*LinuxOS only*) [Free Up and Release the Unused/Cached Memory in Ubuntu/Linux Mint](http://www.yourownlinux.com/2013/10/how-to-free-up-release-unused-cached-memory-in-linux.html) before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*.

---

### Additional Notes

The error *...there is not enough space on the disk...* may not necessary be caused by running out of storage capacity apparently as it seems but can also happen due to running out of `i-nodes` on the filesystem.

> You can find a detailed documentation in [No space left on device – running out of Inodes](https://www.ivankuznetsov.com/2010/02/no-space-left-on-device-running-out-of-inodes.html)

---

### Outro

[WebDriver is not deleting the profile directory after test exits](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/1934)