# How to remove the rust_mozprofile used by Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, firefox, marionette, geckodriver

I have used selenium with python for a while and I recently discovered that my tmp dir is full of rust_mozprofile directories. How can I have them deleted on the fly?

I read in another post that I should use `driver.quit()` instead of `driver.close()` but I am already using driver.quit().

Answer (score 1):

As per the discussion [Is it Firefox or Geckodriver, which creates “rust_mozprofile” directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46088442/is-it-firefox-or-geckodriver-which-creates-rust-mozprofile-directory/46089240#46089240) `rust_mozprofile` directories are created by [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45329528/which-firefox-browser-versions-supported-for-given-geckodriver-version/45331403#45331403) and [Marionette](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44530302/how-can-geckodriver-firefox-work-without-marionette-running-python-selenium-3/44537094#44537094) while initiating a new *Browsing Context* i.e. *Firefox Browser* session.

Ideally, invoking `quit()` should delete them all. You can find a detailed discussion in [Selenium : How to stop geckodriver process impacting PC memory, without calling driver.quit()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47999568/selenium-how-to-stop-geckodriver-process-impacting-pc-memory-without-calling/48003289#48003289)

As an alternate, you can use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the [os](/questions/tagged/os) chores before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*.

Answer (score 0):

you could do this by killing firefox session that had not been quit properly and then delete /tmp/ files created by the session.

```
pkill firefox
find /tmp -type f -delete
```